# I have tried using long both as the variable type as well as the return type of the function but still it is overflowing. I cannot understand why?

Tags: java

I am calling the getMaxPairwiseProduct() method and but it is returning overflow value of the "product" variable. I am already using the long and the product actually is in the limits of long but I cannot understand why it is returning overflow value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MaxPairwiseProduct {

    static long getMaxPairwiseProduct(int[] array){
        //int product =0 ;
        int n = array.length;
        //for(int j =0; j<n ; ++j){
        //}
        QuickSort(array, 0, array.length -1 );
        int n1 = (array[array.length-1]);
        int n2 = (array[array.length-2]);
         long product =n1 * n2;  
         System.out.println(product);
         return product;
}

        private static void QuickSort(int[] arr,  int left, int right){
            int index = partition(arr,left, right);
            if(left < index - 1)
                QuickSort(arr, left, index -1);
            if(index < right)
                QuickSort(arr, index, right);

            //System.out.println(index);
        }
    private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right){
        int pivot = arr[(left + right )/2];
        while(left<=right){
            while(arr[left] < pivot) left++;
            while(arr[right] > pivot) right--;

            if(left<= right){
                int temp= arr[left];
                arr[left] = arr[right];
                arr[right]  =temp;

                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        /*int n = sc.nextInt();
          int[] array = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i <n;++i){
          array[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }
         */
        int[] array = new int[]{100000, 90000};
         long product = getMaxPairwiseProduct(array);
         System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to change `n1` and `n2` to `long`'s. `n1 * n2` is computed it to be an `int` which is then *converted* to a `long`, hence still overflowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, in Java, every integer (non-decimal) number is treated as `int` by default, your line:

```
long product =n1 * n2;
```

Will multiply two `int` values which will overflow and only once the overflowed result is obtained it will be cast to long and saved in `product` variable.

**Fix ?**

Cast one of your two operands to `long` explicitly, something like this would work:

```
long product = (long)n1 * n2;
```

Java will automatically start working with "biggest" data type, so since you are multiplying `long` and `int`, the `int` or `n2` will be implicitly converted to `long` as well, no overflow will occur and you should get correct result.